# typescript expected '=>' in function type declaration

Tags: typescript, types, callback

I have an interface where i define the structure of a callback like so:

```
interface SliderOptions {
    onCreateSlide?: (slide: Slide) => void;
    onSlideTransition?: (slide: Slide, offset: number, onTransitionComplete: () => void); // generates typescript compiler error. 
    // more options etc
}
```

but i get the follow error, see image below:

[image]

Why is this happening i dont get it, since the line right above it doesnt generate this error and does about the same thing imo.

Comment: Try `onSlideTransition?: (slide: Slide, offset: number, onTransitionComplete: () => void)=> void;`

Comment: yeah that fixed, no clue how i managed to miss something that obvious... Post it as an answer if you want, i will accept it

Comment: Happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two functions returning void `onSlideTransition` and `onTransitionComplete`, so it should be
`onSlideTransition?: (slide: Slide, offset: number, onTransitionComplete: () => void)=> void;`